# Python Tkinter - Trying to for each through dynamically created entries

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a list of tkinter entry fields generated dynamically. I need to grab the contents of each field while knowing what it's referring to. I have tried adding something like `"entry"+count = Entry(..)` but as expected it wont work like that and is really quite a stupid design practice to attempt so I'm thinking it needs to be in the form of an array but can't seem to figure out how to do that with an Entry.

```
rowNum = 0
items = []

def tableGen(name):
    global rowNum
    entry = Entry(win).grid(row=rowNum, column=0)
    label = Label(win, text=name).grid(row=rowNum, column=1)
    self.items[rowNum] = [entry, label] # Problem Area 1
    rowNum += 1

def generate(): # Print each items value
    for item in items:
        print (item.get()) # Problem Area 2

# Generates Entrys and labels from file
e = ET.parse('file.xml').getroot()
for atype in e.findall('things'):
    tableGen(atype.get('name'))

generateBtn = Button(root, text="Generate", command=generate).pack()

generate()
root.mainloop()
```

I've simplifed the code to the minimal required to see what I'm trying to do. The problem seems to be either with where I put the items in a table or try and parse them (problem are 1 & 2). I'm very new to python and can't figure out how to do this. In it's current state the project fails with `in tableGen self.items[rowNum] = [entry, label] Name Error: name 'self' is not defined`.

Am I doing this wrong? Is there another way this can be done?

---

**Solution**

```
rowNum = 0
items = []

def tableGen(name):
    global rowNum
    entry = Entry(win)
    entry.grid(row=rowNum, column=0)
    label = Label(win, text=name)
    label.grid(row=rowNum, column=1)
    items.append([entry, label])
    rowNum += 1

def generate(): # Print each items value
    for item in items:
        print('Entry:', item[0].get(), 'Label:', item[1].cget("text"))

# Generates Entrys and labels from file
e = ET.parse('file.xml').getroot()
for atype in e.findall('things'):
    tableGen(atype.get('name'))

generateBtn = Button(root, text="Generate", command=generate).pack()

generate()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try `print item[0].get()`.

Comment: If you are in python 3, you must use print(item.get())

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I just tried that with no luck, same with `print items.get(item)`

Comment: @Joe omg.. I feel so dumb now.. that's what I forgot. at least I'm getting errors relating to my underlying problem now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`append()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types) to add items to the end of a list:

```
def tableGen(name):
    ...
    items.append([entry, label])
    rowNum += 1
```

This will generate a list of lists, so you need to use an index to access the elements of each item:

```
def generate(): # Print each items value
    for item in items:
        print('Entry:', item[0].get(), 'Label:', item[1].get())
```

Comment: This makes a bunch of sense and It got partially there except i'm getting an error of `AttributeError: 'noneType' object has no attribute 'get'` is it breaking because i'm storing an entry and a label?

Comment: I had to move `.grid(...)` to a new line and add it to the entry and label to fix the noneType error. and labels don't have a `get()` so all fixed!